# getSupportFragmentManager() returns null FragmentManager when setting adapter from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

My Activity extend Sliding Fragment Activity, First time I have set adapter for my viewpager successfully. But when I try to set it again from Broadcast Receiver that is from inside onReceive() method then getSupportFragmentManager() returns me null. I have searched a lot for this but found nothing that have helped me.

Comment: If I set viewpager adapter on button(in my Activity) click then it is working fine means then getSupportFragmentManager() returns FragmentManager instance. But Problem occurs only when I call it from onReceive() method of BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want do this from broadcast receiver ?

Broadcast receiver don't have acces to the UI, but you can send an intent to your activity to perform some action.

> Send intent from broadcast to activity
>
> Activity get the intent in onNewIntent (Intent intent){...} - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)